# How can I make word for mac docs open in front of the current application, not behind

Tags: finder, mail.app, ms-office, big-sur

Before I upgraded to Big Sur my word docs used to open in front of whatever application I was using, e.g. Finder, Mail. Now when I open a Word doc from Finder or a Mac Mail attachment it opens behind the current screen. So I have to minimise or close the current app to be able to see the Word document, or swipe to mission control to go find it.

It used to be easy, now its infuriating. Is there a way to set it up to open in front - where I obviously want to see it?

Comment: This is a Microsoft Office issue, and would need to be addressed by Microsoft.

Comment: @EzekielElin Let's see whether there is some configuration which causes this

Comment: Is this behaviour just Word?  Or does the same thing happened with a) Excel, and b) Text Edit (or other non-MS apps)?  Answers will tells whether this is a Word settings issue, an MS/Office issue or a system wide setting.  Also tell us what version of Word.